# Why Is My Wordpress Page.php Not Redirecting?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I bought a site and migrated the files to my hosting, and I have a page that is not redirecting properly. This is the page:

http://www.flatshoesforwomen.net/home.php

It should redirect to the link on the page but it's not doing so. There are a few other pages that are doing the same thing. Can anyone explain the fix to a non-programmer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which URL are you trying to redirect to? `flatshoesforwomen.net`?

Comment: We cannot see your php code on that page.  PHP has already finished running once you load a page into the browser.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to go to flatshoesforwomen.net.

Comment: Should be able to get that whole domain to redirect through host. Want to make sure that proper headers are set so search bots will re-index also

Answer (score 0):

Change your `home.php` file. The part before the `<body>` tag currently looks like

```
<html> <head>  <title>Foot Pain And Its Types</title>
```

You want to insert instructions for the browser to go somewhere else after a few seconds. You also want to properly close the `<head>` tag. So replace the above with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foot Pain And Its Types</title>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.flatshoesforwomen.net/">
</head>
```

You can change `5` with `3` if you want redirection after 3 seconds.  The rest of the page, from the opening `<body>` tag, can stay the same.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: Cleaner to do server side redirect. No need to double load pages that way. Can also set status header for search bots

Comment: Agreed, but notice the caveat in the question `Can anyone explain the fix to a non-programmer?` I opted for the easiest solution to implement given that the OP seems to want the old page to be shown with the redirect message, then the user to be redirected to the new page. Perhaps you can write up an answer that explains in simple terms your solution. If the OP understands & implements it that's great.